# ckeditor5 list item start number

Tags: ckeditor5

Trying to build a plugin to set start attribute for `ol` in ckEditor5.

As best I can tell, the model contains a collection of `listItems`.

The start attribute would need to be set on the `ol` however, the parent of the list item, not on the list item itself.. is there a way to access the `ol` from the model?

I can get the current `li` with

```
first(editor.model.document.selection.getSelectedBlocks())
```

is there a way set an attribute on the `ol` element?

**EDIT -- code to get attribute on LI:**

```
editor.model.schema.extend('listItem', { allowAttributes: 'listStart' });

editor.conversion.attributeToAttribute({ 
  model: 'listStart', 
  view: 'start'
});
```

enables in the model: `<listItem type="numbered" listStart="4">`, which will translate to this in the view:

```
<ol>
  <li start="4">words</li>
</ol>
```

what I am trying to achieve is

```
<ol start="4">
  <li>words</li>
</ol>
```

When I examine source, its looks as though the `ol` (or `ul`) is automatically created here:

```
function generateLiInUl( modelItem, conversionApi ) {

    const mapper = conversionApi.mapper;
    const viewWriter = conversionApi.writer;
    const listType = modelItem.getAttribute( 'listType' ) == 'numbered' ? 'ol' : 'ul';
    const viewItem = createViewListItemElement( viewWriter );
  // ** OL or UL created here -->
    const viewList = viewWriter.createContainerElement( listType, null );
        viewWriter.insert( ViewPosition.createAt( viewList ), viewItem );

    mapper.bindElements( modelItem, viewItem );

    return viewItem;
}
```

[link to source](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/blob/master/src/converters.js)

Is there an event I could observe? Or is there a way in the conversion definition to target the attribute on the parent?

**UPDATE 2**

If we are going to mod source, we can intercept the downcast by adding this to the `generateLiInUl` function (thanks MTilsted):

```
    const listStart = modelItem.getAttribute('listStart');
    if (listStart) {
        viewWriter.setAttribute('start', listStart, viewList);
    }
```

and to facilitate upcast add this to the `viewModelConverter` function

```
    const listStart = data.viewItem.parent.getAttribute('start');
    if (listStart) {
        writer.setAttribute( 'listStart', listStart, listItem );
    }
```

It's a little ugly in that we are modifying source which is a pita for maintenance, and on upcast we are adding the `listStart` attribute to every `listItem` element in the model.. but its a start.

I looked briefly into adding dispatchers.. eg:

```
data.upcastDispatcher.on( 'element:li', myCustomUpcastFunction );
```

but could not figure out how to get a reference to `listItem` element that was added to the model in the `viewModelConverter` function mentioned above.

Comment: If I remember correct, the li is a child of ol, so just try first(editor.model.document.selection.getSelectedBlocks()).parent But in order to set a custom element on ol, you need to modify the schema

Comment: Thanks @MTilsted .. I think the issue is that the ol does not exist in the model, only the list item.  The ol gets created in the view only (as best i can tell) -- so I think I'd have to set the attribute on the list item, and edit the list feature to catch that attribute and apply to the ol... and that sounds difficult and dangerous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that worked for me was very simple and I feel kinda silly not seeing it earlier:  Use the LI `value` attribute instead of the OL `start` attribute.

```
<ol>
  <li value="4">words</li>
</ol>
```

instead of:

```
<ol start="4">
  <li>words</li>
</ol>
```

This keeps the attribute on the listItem and avoids all the complication (I completely missed the existence of the LI's value attribute in my original attempt):

```
editor.model.schema.extend('listItem', { allowAttributes: 'value' });

editor.conversion.attributeToAttribute({ 
  model: 'value', 
  view: 'value'
});
```

The command to apply the value:

```
execute(arg) {

  let val = arg.value;
  const model = this.editor.model;
  const block = first(model.document.selection.getSelectedBlocks());

  model.change(writer => {
    if (+val) {
      writer.setAttribute('value', val, block);
    } else {
      writer.removeAttribute('value', block);
    }
  });

}
```

and to prevent the value being copied to next LI on enter:

```
editor.commands.get('enter').on('afterExecute', () => {
  const block = first(editor.model.document.selection.getSelectedBlocks());
  if ( block.name == 'listItem' && block.hasAttribute('value')) {
    editor.model.change( writer => {
      writer.removeAttribute('value', block);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated:
Ok the way the generate lists work are odd. Which may have something to do with the way lists are merged, and change type. I must admit I don't really understand how that part works.

I could not find a way to downcast the attribute as you need, So unless someone from Cksource come around, the only solution I could find is to patch the list code. And I am not sure how well that works with upcast. (Only lightly tested).

But in the file node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/converters.js

Just try to add this line:

```
viewWriter.setAttribute('start',model.getAttribute('listStart'),viewList);
```

To the method

```
function generateLiInUl( modelItem, conversionApi ) {
```

In my version of ckeditor(The newest) it should be added on line 810.

Original answer(Usefull but not for lists).

Oh yes. You are right about the model. But the entire point of the design in ckeditor 5 is that you don't have to modify the existing plugin to add attributes. You can register the extra attribute with the schema and then add a matching DowncastElementToElement in your own plugin.

Here is my code I use to add extra attributes to the image class. It should be trivial to change to work on listItems instead. (Cut/Pasted from different places in my code, so I may have forgotten something, but try it. And if you can't get it to work, I will make a fully working example monday :)

```
        model.schema.extend('image', {
            allowAttributes: ['displaywidth','ignorecolumns','fullpagepicture']
        } );

    editor.conversion.for('upcast')
                .add(upcastAttributeToAttribute( { model: 'isvisible', view: 'isvisible' }))
                .add(upcastAttributeToAttribute( { model: 'displaywidth', view: 'displaywidth' }))
                .add(upcastAttributeToAttribute( { model: 'fullpagepicture', view: 'fullpagepicture' }))

editor.conversion.for('downcast')
        .add(downcastAttributeToAttribute( { model: 'isvisible', view: 'isvisible' }))
        .add(downcastAttributeToAttribute( { model: 'displaywidth', view: 'displaywidth' }))
        .add(downcastAttributeToAttribute( { model: 'fullpagepicture', view: 'fullpagepicture' }))
```

Comment: Thanks @MTilsted  I added some code to the question to clarify the issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess @Steve has already solved his problem, but his issue helped me understood my own. Therefore, I want to help those in need like me.

First of all, I note that is not normal to change built-in plugins as suggested earlier and do that. CKEditor creators encourage us to use our custom plugins which overwrite built-in logic. So, use CKEditor API to change an editor behavior.

And my solution is

```js
// @ckeditor/ckeditor5-core@25.0.0
import Plugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin' 

export class ListStartAttribute extends Plugin {
    init() {
        console.log('ListStartAttribute is init')
        const editor = this.editor

        // 1.extend schema
        editor.model.schema.extend('listItem', { allowAttributes: 'start' })

        // 2.set conversion up/down
        editor.conversion.for('downcast').add(dispatcher => {
            dispatcher.on('attribute', (evt, data, conversionApi) => {

                if (data.item.name != 'listItem') {
                    return
                }

                const viewWriter = conversionApi.writer
                const viewElement = conversionApi.mapper.toViewElement(
                    data.item
                )
                const containerElement = viewElement.parent

                if (
                    data.attributeNewValue &&
                    !containerElement.getAttribute('start')
                ) {
                    viewWriter.setAttribute(
                        data.attributeKey,
                        data.attributeNewValue,
                        containerElement
                    )
                }
            })
        })

        editor.conversion.for('upcast').attributeToAttribute({
            model: {
                name: 'listItem',
                key: 'start',
            },
            view: {
                name: 'ol',
                key: 'start',
            },
            converterPriority: 'low',
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dmitry K., could you please share the rest of the code, such as the command code where you set the parameter for the start attribute? Much appreciated!